# android send binary data in http

Tags: android, http, bitmap

I have the following code to send an image (bitmap binary data) using android http default client:

```
//gets raw binary data and convert it to a string
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String imageData = new String(imageBytes);
//http put body
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(imageData);
putRequest.setEntity(se);
```

I need to send its raw binary content in the put request body, but it seems that the content is not being properly sent.

I can send an image binary using curl with the --data-binary (that's what I am trying to do in android).

Is the process in converting the bitmap binary to string correct?

Thanks!

Comment: No that process is not correct. You better take imageBytes and encode them to a base64 string. Then you have a correct String.

Comment: I cannot send the string in a base64 format, it needs to be raw data binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my bad.

In case anyone makes the same mistake:

I should have used the ByteArrayEntity class instead of the StringEntity one:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
//http put body
ByteArrayEntity be = new ByteArrayEntity(imageBytes);
putRequest.setEntity(be);
```

I was trying to convert the bytearray into a string and send it, the correct way to do it is to use the ByteArrayEntity class.